# Cannot install Python from source on Apple Silicon M1

Tags: python, makefile, clang, ld

I am trying to install Python from source according to the readme using:

```
./configure
make <-- Error happens here
make test
sudo make altinstall
```

However, I cannot complete the `make` command since it fails with:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_libintl_bindtextdomain", referenced from:
      __locale_bindtextdomain in _localemodule.o
  "_libintl_dcgettext", referenced from:
      __locale_dcgettext in _localemodule.o
  "_libintl_dgettext", referenced from:
      __locale_dgettext in _localemodule.o
  "_libintl_gettext", referenced from:
      __locale_gettext in _localemodule.o
  "_libintl_setlocale", referenced from:
      __locale_setlocale in _localemodule.o
      __locale_localeconv in _localemodule.o
  "_libintl_textdomain", referenced from:
      __locale_textdomain in _localemodule.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Programs/_freeze_module] Error 1
```

Looks like `make` is somehow using the wrong architecture. I just don't know why. Does anyone have an idea?

EDIT: I stumbled across this bug report: https://bugs.python.org/issue46975

I have indeed brew x86_64 (and arm64) installed and it seems that this somehow interferes. `make --version` generates this output:

```
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
...
This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
```

shouldn't it be `arm64-apple-darwin11.3.0`? And is there a way to just use the `make` from macOS and ignore all the other stuff from `brew`?

Comment: I can recommend pyenv for installing multiple Python versions from source on Mac (or any other platform for that matter). It compiles Python just fine on my M1 MacBook.